# can we have different features for different hyperplanes in SVM?

Tags: svm, multilabel-classification

is it possible if we have different features for different classes of svm?

For example one of the hyperplane:

$$w_1\cdot \text{age}+ w_2 \cdot \text{ trip duration} +w_3 \cdot \text{ income}$$

and the other hyperplane be

$$w_1\cdot \text{cost}+ w_2 \cdot \text{trip duration} +w_3 \cdot \text{purpose of trip}$$

the other one

$$w_1\cdot \text{distance}+ w_2 \cdot \text{trip duration} +w_3 \cdot 0?$$

Does it make sense?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible.

All of these hyperplanes live in the space of

$$\text{(age, trip duration, income, cost, purpose of trip, distace)}$$

even though some of the coefficients are $0$.

Remark: For the last hyperplane $w_3\cdot 0 = 0$.

Comment: no I mean if my data is in 3 dimension

Comment: and what are those $3$ dimensions? You can only use features from your data.

Comment: I can make my data with 3 columns, for some row the first column is age and for some of them cost and some of them distance. same for other columns

Comment: Hence, you are partitioning your data set into $3$ subdata set? Why do you want to do that? Is it due to difficulty in data collections?

Comment: reducing the dimension of problem

Comment: but you are not really doing that isn't it, you still use all features to build $3$ different models. You might like to think about what causes a data to be in a subdata. Also, what about the test data behavior.You can do feature selections and build a model if that is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

It is common in multi-class systems to have several different models. These models could conceivably rely on very different feature sets.

One model could rely on features {A,B,C,D} for separating out A from BC. Then another model could be found and tuned with features {D,E,F,G} such that model #2  separates separate B from C.

It is also common to have an "Ensemble" approach to working with multi-class systems, datasets and predictors.